# Does the Amazon SP-API getOrderAddress operation work outside the sandbox?

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api, pii

As far as I know, there 2 kinds of developer access for the Amazon SP-API: one that allows access to Personally Identifiable information (PII) and one that doesn't.

My Amazon SP-API developer profile is NOT supposed to have access to PII, however, when I send sandbox [getOrderAddress](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference#getorderaddress) requests to the Amazon SP-API I get a successful response; I also know that the response is static and it's always the same for everybody but my request doesn't get rejected.

I don't have access to a production store that has orders so that I can test this and the documentation doesn't have any special notes that indicate whether or not the "higher" developer access is required for the operation.

My questions are simple:

- With my current developer access, will I be able to perform the getOrderAddress call on production stores and get the orders' address information?
- Will the request be rejected in production or will it return empty data?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/regulated-orders), only certain operations in the Orders API require a Restricted Data Token to access the information. I was able to call the getOrders operation in the sandbox successfully, although I do not have access to PII, but the UpdateVerificationStatus operation returned Unauthorized. I believe this does not reflect the reality in production; see [this](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/changelog/important-notice-discontinued-support-lwa-tokens-can-no-longer-retrieve-pii-in-selling-partner-api) update from Amazon on which operations require an RDT.